# Pushing to array more user-specified values

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, foreach

I made simple class to make my work at school faster.
Theres one function:

```
function selectWhere($what, $from, $where) {

    $sql = "SELECT ".$what." FROM ".$from." WHERE ".$where;
    if($result = $this->conn->query($sql)) {
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $a = Array();
            if(strpos($what, ", ")) {
                $exp = explode(", ", $what);
                while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    foreach ($exp as $key => $val) {
                        $a[] = $r[$val];
                    }
                }
                return $a;
            }
            else {
                while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $a[] = $r[$what];
                }
                return $a;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return "Błędne zapytanie.";
    }
}
```

Which works great until I want to select more than one column. Basically output of this code looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => LeviPlayGames [1] => leviplaygames [2] => TestUser [3] => testuser )
```

Which is result of selecting name and realname column. Now working with code forced me to use multidimesional array, so the desired output will be like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => LeviPlayGames [1] => leviplaygames ) [1] => Array ( [0] => TestUser [1] => testuser ) )
```

So results will be separated, but I can't find out how to connect two (or more) columns in array. As far as I know I have to change my foreach, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
 $a[$key][] = $r[$val];
```

instead of:

```
 $a[] = $r[$val];
```

should be all that is needed to insert the results in the appropriate subarray and get your desired output.